# How can I Programmatically log in as a user without a password

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, .net

We have a requirement that an administrator can "impersonate" any user to view the site in order to help guide that user over the phone on how to use the site.

We will need a textbox for example where the Administrator will need to enter the username to impersonate and when submitting, the administrator is logged in to the site as the impersonated user.

Any guidance how this can be done?

SP2013, FBA

Comment: It is easy to impersonate a user programmatically in SharePoint, so you could technically develop a feature that deploys a control that allows the farm admin or site collection admins to impersonate users. I have not seen or done such an implementation, but I hope this info can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Why using "impersonation" to *"guide users over the phone on how to use the site"*? The only reason I can think of is to allow the administrator to "see" the site as the user, so that he can ensure that there aren't any visibility problems due to permissions and such. I don't believe there is any way to do this: the only idea that comes to mind is to rewrite the auth cookie based on the impersonated user token. Even if this can work somehow (and I hope it doesn't) it would seem an extreme security issue to allow this.Have you considered remote control instead? Teamviewer could be a solution

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, indeed another reason is to be able to see the site as the user and make sure any changes are deployed correctly and no permission issues.